# jquery li binding ul syntax issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I am dynamically adding li tag to UL .the following is very complex li tag with which i am getting syntax issue.Could any one please help me to fix following tag.
Any basic tutorials to form these kind of links also great.

I am trying to bind link with some conditions.on click of a link it opens a new page .

```js
notifcationUL.append('<li><div class="pull-left"><a href="javascript:window.open(<%=ResolveUrl("~/App Web Pages/Generic/PageTableUIControl.aspx?Entity=Notifications&EntityObject=EIS_Notifications&UpdateModeLoad=false&WhereCondition=Main.[NotificationUserID]='"+ $("#hdnUser").val() + "' and Main.NotificationCreatedDate='" + today + "'%>",mywindowtitle)"><strong>See All Notifications</strong><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></div><div class="pull-right"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-info removenotifications">Clear Notifications <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash pull-right "></span></a></div></li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add server side asp code to the page on the client side with jquery :/

You're doing something fundamentally wrong. Can you edit your question explaining what you're trying to archieve?

Comment: Resolve url can be used client side jquery. i have modified the  code.Can you pls check and let me know where i am making mistake

Answer (score 0):

Your quotations are off . When you append anything with jQuery the inner quotes must be opposite of outside quotation . See below.

your syntax :

```
notifcationUL.append('<li><div class="pull-left"><a href="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/App Web Pages/Generic/PageTableUIControl.aspx?Entity=Notifications&EntityObject=EIS_Notifications&UpdateModeLoad=false&WhereCondition=Main.[NotificationUserID]='"+ $('#hdnUser").val() + "' and Main.NotificationCreatedDate=" + today + '%>","mywindowtitle")"><strong>See All Notifications</strong><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></div><div class="pull-right"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-info removenotifications">Clear Notifications <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash pull-right "></span></a></div></li>');
```

correct syntax :

```
notifcationUL.append('<li><div class="pull-left"><a href="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/App Web Pages/Generic/PageTableUIControl.aspx?Entity=Notifications&EntityObject=EIS_Notifications&UpdateModeLoad=false&WhereCondition=Main.[NotificationUserID]="' + $("#hdnUser").val() + '" and Main.NotificationCreatedDate=" '+ today + '"%>","mywindowtitle")"><strong>See All Notifications</strong><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></div><div class="pull-right"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-info removenotifications">Clear Notifications <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash pull-right "></span></a></div></li>');
```

Comment: I'm staring for a long time and don't see a difference between the two :S

Comment: use in the diff checker and you'll see the difference in each line  --->>>  https://www.diffchecker.com/